# ARP table does not show my most recent ping to cisco.com

Tags: networking

As you may have guessed by the question title I have a lot to learn about networking in general. That being said I am unsure why my ARP table does not show a recently pinged address, or if it is suppose to. After pinging cisco.com my ARP table shows the following:

(ARP command performed from my laptop running win7, this was not done on a switch or router)

Interface: 10.209.226.154 --- 0xc
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.209.226.1          00-00-0c-07-ac-e2     dynamic
  10.209.226.21         9c-93-4e-28-ca-e8     dynamic
  10.209.226.22         00-00-aa-ce-d5-20     dynamic
  10.209.226.29         00-1a-4b-1d-d7-4a     dynamic
  10.209.226.59         2c-44-fd-62-7d-39     dynamic
  10.209.226.69         d8-9d-67-98-92-b7     dynamic
  10.209.226.71         a0-b3-cc-4b-8a-39     dynamic
  10.209.226.99         00-1a-a0-6f-10-cd     dynamic
  10.209.226.133        18-a9-05-2a-da-a4     dynamic
  10.209.226.161        78-e3-b5-cb-e8-65     dynamic
  10.209.226.172        f0-92-1c-5c-a8-2b     dynamic
  10.209.226.192        00-21-70-9b-f8-aa     dynamic
  10.209.226.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.192.83.80         01-00-5e-40-53-50     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  239.255.255.253       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Interface: 172.19.43.226 --- 0xd
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  172.19.32.1           00-00-0c-07-ac-20     dynamic
  172.19.47.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  239.255.255.253       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Here we see the rest of the devices on my LAN that I frequently communicate with and their corresponding MAC addresses.  A series of devices are listed within the 10.209.226.0 subnet that  appear to have been learned dynamically, meaning my device learned the MAC’s  of these other devices by being told by the other devices. At the end of the  list of devices in the 10.209.226.0 subnet the IP address changes to 224.0.0.2 which are all static, which would imply that these MAC address are programmed into the network devices on this particular subnet.

This is about as far as I have gotten in understanding the output. If anyone could help me understand why I dont see the cisco.com ping, I would appreciate as well.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You need to read more. ARP converts for example an IP address into an link layer (frequently Ethernet) address. Unless you are on the same link-layer as cisco.com you won't see it's link-layer address.

Answer (score 6):

1. MAC addresses don't transit routers. You will never see the MAC address of a host that is not on the same subnet as your host.
2. The 224 and 239 ip/MAC addresses are multicast addresses and it is perfectly normal to see them in your ARP table. For more info, see here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address